# JavaScript Check Date not today or in the past

Tags: javascript

JavaScript Check Date not today or in the past.

```
var c = '10 JUN 2010'; // this is the format of the date coming in.
var temp = new Array();
temp = c.split(' ');

var x = new Date ( temp[1]+" "+temp[0]+", "+temp[2] );

if (x.getTime() > getDate()) {
   alertstring = alertstring + '\n\nDEBUG CODE: 1 ' + x + '\n\n';
}
```

I cannot change the format coming in.

Comment: Look at `Date.parse`. You don't need to do that split. `var x = new Date(Date.parse(c))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you 99% have it.  Here it is with a modified if condition:

```
var c = '10 JUN 2010'; // this is the format of the date coming in.
var temp = new Array();
temp = c.split(' ');

var x = new Date ( temp[1]+" "+temp[0]+", "+temp[2] );

if (x.getTime() > (new Date().getTime())) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Only bad thing is I read the split may not work in IE7 is that true?

Answer (score 2):

Update this line:

```
// Get current date and time
var today = new Date();

// strip time to compare to the parse date
if (x.getTime() > new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()).getTime()) {
    // this date has not happened yet.
    alertstring = alertstring + '\n\nDEBUG CODE: 1 ' + x + '\n\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in constructor the number of month
Instead of string .
Instead of June put 6.